# Cut bytes of data received as a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, printf, byte, cut

Hi I am receiving string data bytes from a TCP connection which looks like this :

**00500060001157 1158 1159 1160**

First I want to print the entire string received and then I want to separate out the data 1157, 1158, 1159 and 1160 from this input data and print them separately. How do I do that?

Comment: Before you do anything with the data you got rom the TCP socket, make absolutely certain that you got all of the data. No more and no less. Remember that TCP is a stream and doesn't observe any logical organization you have applied to the data in the stream.

Comment: One approach is to take the bytes read from the TCP stream and store them in a `std::istringstream`. You then read the tokens from the `istringstream` the same way you would from `std::cin`.